# Python ggplot histogram binwidth and bins arguments not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, histogram, python-ggplot

I'm using yhat's ggplot in Python together with a pandas dataframe. When creating a histogram the `bins`- and `binwidth`-argument are completely ignored. Example:

```
import ggplot as gp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed()
num=1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(num)})

gp.ggplot(gp.aes(x='A'),data=df) + gp.geom_histogram(bins=0.1)
```

It doesn't matter how I set `bins` or `binwidth`, I'm always getting the same image, the arguments do have no effect at all.

I'm following exactly the examples in the doc: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_histogram.html

I have seen other sites giving examples using that syntax suggesting that it's supposed to work normal, so what am I missing here?

```
ggplot 0.10.4
Python 2.7
```